# Fetching data using MultiProvider in main.dart only returns null (breaks Flutter app)

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

On Sunday 1st October I was developing my Flutter app (only making styling changes) and everything was fine and dandy. Then the following morning, my app wouldn't open because no data was being fetched and the app was caught in an endless error: `Null check operator used on a null value`. What's confusing is that I didn't do any Flutter software updates or anything to change the code about the Provider package. The app screen is blank and nothing loads.

I thought it was the database I was using, but when I make a request in their online console, data is returned, so it's not that. Currently, this is the set up of `Providers` and `Consumers` in my application.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CategoryProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => VenueProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ArtistProvider()),
      ],
      child: Sizer(builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Art app',
```

Below is an example of the VenueProvider (the two others follow exactly the same format):

```
class VenueProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final VenueService _service = VenueService();
  bool isLoading = false;
  List<Venue?>? _allVenues;
  List<Venue?>? get allVenues => _allVenues;

  getAllVenues() async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final response = await _service.getAllVenues();

    _allVenues = response;
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Finally, this is the VenueService (the actual GET request):

```
class VenueService {
  Future<List<Venue?>?> getAllVenues() async {
    var query = DataQueryBuilder()..sortBy = ['created DESC'];
    var dbdata = await Backendless.data.withClass<Venue>().find(query);
    return dbdata;
  }
}
```

I checked the Provider package (last updated 9 months ago), I tried reverting changes back to that beautiful Sunday when everything worked and I tried. (but failed) to wrap all of the areas in `try catch` blocks, no luck!  I've run out of things to try so am hoping someone can help me!  Also the only thing `flutter doctor` says is I need to update Xcode, but I am only running this on android for now.

Any pointers, tips or suggestions are welcome!!!

Thank youuuuuuu